# pytest-django django_db_server fixture not working

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I would like to use a specialized test database for unit testing my Django app. I'm using `pytest` along with `pytest-django`. Per the `pytest-django` instructions, I provided my own custom `django_db_setup` fixture in a `conftest.py` file as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pytest
from django.conf import settings


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    base_dir = Path(__file__).parent
    path = base_dir / 'test_db.sqlite3'
    assert path.exists()
    assert path.is_file()

    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': path
    }
```

I can confirm that this code is being executed when I run unit tests, and the `test_db.sqlite3` database is being found. However, the unit tests are still referring to my development database **not** my test database.

How do I get `pytest-django` to reference my test database instead of my development database?

Answer (score 0):

I just started exploring pytest and pytest-django like few days ago but i'm using a test database by creating a pytest.ini file in my project root folder like so:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myproject.test_settings
```

folder tree is something like this:

```
myproject
  |  
  ------app_one
  |
  ------myproject
    |
    ------settings.py
    |
    --------test_settings.py
```

the test_settings.py file looks like this

```
from .settings import *


DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": "db_test.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

you could checkmore about this in the [docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html).